# Actionscript 3 error 1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, animate-cc

I'm trying to make a simple game on Animate CC. Everything seems to work fine except when I look in the output, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.
>   at _2D_CW2_Game_v10_8_fla::MainTimeline/move()
>   at _2D_CW2_Game_v10_8_fla::MainTimeline/updateOb()

So I know where the issue might be, and I've been trying tweaking the code for days, googling possible solutions, but to no avail...

My entire source code is as below. Any feedback/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;


//==================================================    
// Variable declaration 
//==================================================

// defines the variables for boundaries
var left:Number = 0;
var top:Number = 0;
var right:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var bottom:Number = stage.stageHeight; 

var velX:Number = 0;
var velY:Number = 0;
var gravity:Number = 1;
var friction:Number = 0.8;
var bounce:Number = -0.5;
var score:Number = 2;
var cv:Number = 0;
var curCount:Number = 30; // countdown 30s

var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var touchGround:Boolean = false;

// create and place player object on stage
var player:Player = new Player();
player.x = 110;
player.y = 460;
addChild(player);

// create obstacle array
var obstacles:Array = new Array();
var numOb:Number = 3;

// create and place enemies on stage
for (var i:Number = 0; i < numOb; i++) {
    var ob:Npc = new Npc();
    ob.x = 800;
    ob.y = 470;
    ob.scaleX = -1;
    ob.vx = Math.random() * 20 + 1;
    addChild(ob);
    obstacles.push(ob);
}


//==================================================    
// Event handlers   
//==================================================

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EntFrame);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateOb);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);


//==================================================    
// Functions    
//==================================================

function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightKeyDown = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftKeyDown = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        // if player isn't already jumping and is on the ground
        if (!upKeyDown && touchGround) {
            // then start jumping
            isJumping();
        }
        upKeyDown = true;
    }
}

function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        rightKeyDown = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        leftKeyDown = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        upKeyDown = false;
    }
}

function EntFrame(e:Event):void {
    player.x += velX;
    player.y += velY;   
    velX *= friction;
    velY += gravity;
    if (player.y >= 450) {
        touchGround = true;
        player.y = 450;
    }
    // boundary checks
    if (player.x + player.width/2 > right) {
        player.x = right - player.width/2;
        player.velX *= bounce;
    } else if (player.x - player.width/2 < left) {
        player.x = left + player.width/2;
        player.velX *= bounce;
    }
    // make player move left or right
    controls();
    if (curCount > 0) {
        cv++;
        if (cv >= 30) {
            curCount--;
            cv = 0;
            timertext.text = String(curCount);
            if (curCount == 0) {
                restart();
                gotoAndStop("gameOverWon");
            }
        }
    }
}

function updateOb(e:Event):void {
    // make obstacles move
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < numOb; i++) {
        var ob:Npc = obstacles[i];
        move(ob);
        if (player.hitTestObject(obstacles[i])) {
        /*if (obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - player.height/2, true))*/
            bumpOb(obstacles[i]);
        }
    }
    scoretext.text = String(score);
    if (score == 0) {
        restart();
        gotoAndStop("gameOverLost");
    }
}

// applies basic velocity to enemies
function move(moveOb) {
    moveOb.x -= moveOb.vx;
    if (moveOb.x + moveOb.width/2 > right) {
        moveOb.x = right - moveOb.width/2;
        moveOb.vx *= bounce;
        moveOb.scaleX = -1;
    }
    if (moveOb.x - moveOb.width/2 < left) {
        moveOb.x = left + moveOb.width/2;
        moveOb.vx *= bounce;
        moveOb.scaleX = 1;
    }
}

function bumpOb(p) {
    if (p) {
        p.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateOb);
        if (p.parent) {
            removeChild(p);
            score--;
        }
    }
}

function restart() {
    if(contains(player)) {
        removeChild(player);
    }
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numOb; i++) {
        if (contains(obstacles[i]) && obstacles[i] != null) {
            removeChild(obstacles[i]);
            obstacles[i] = null;
        }
    }
    // returns a new array that consists of a range of elements from the original array, 
    // without modifying the original array
    obstacles.slice(0);
}

function controls() {
    if (rightKeyDown) {
        velX += 3;
        player.scaleX = 1;
    }
    if (leftKeyDown) {
        velX -= 3;
        player.scaleX = -1;
    }
}

function isJumping() {
    touchGround = false;
    velY = -15;
}


//==================================================    
// Sound control for background music   
//==================================================

btnMute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mute);

function mute(e:MouseEvent):void {
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
    btnMute.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mute);
    btnMute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unmute);
}

function unmute(e:MouseEvent):void {
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
    btnMute.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unmute);
    btnMute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mute);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  As a tip, rather than just posting all your code, explain what you've actually tried and what you think the issue is.   It's a big time commitment expecting people to sift through your entire code with no explanation other than an error message.

Comment: Most likely, you are splicing your array, but still have a for loop trying to iterate over items that are no longer there.  If iterating over an array, it's always best use the array's length property, not a fixed number - so instead of `i < numOb;` do `i < obstacles.length;`

Comment: Are you sure obstacels[i] is always not null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 error #1009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796709/as3-error-1009)

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis noted thanks. I debugged the movie, the problem seems to be at line `moveOb.x -= moveOb.vx;` in "move(moveOb)" method and `move(ob);` in "updateOb". It tells me `move(ob);`is undefined, but I couldn't figure out why it is undefined...I tried all the suggestions given here, but unfortunately none of them worked :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I created interactive elements for animation. Check which layer the interactive object is on. A similar error occurred when the object overlapped something that was located on the layer above.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try*...

**1)** Your **`Npc`** is a class/library object, right?

Give the source MC/Sprite, the instance name of **`moveOb`** or **`p`**.

**2)** *or else try*... Use **function parameters** *(this is a better coding style)*:

(2a) Since you say..

```
var ob:Npc = obstacles[i];
move(ob);
```

*ps:* *why not simplify (without `var`) as* : `move( obstacles[i] );` ...?

(2b) Your move function should specify a **data type** together with your parameter name...

```
//# applies basic velocity to enemies

//# Wrong... 
//function move(moveOb) {

//# Better... 
function move( moveOb : Npc ) {

//# Aso fix as...
function bumpOb(p : Npc ) {
```

By using function parameters, you can now give unique names to the *(function's)* input parameters but stay referencing the same (or compatible) data type.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, yes Npc is a library object. I've updated my code according to your suggestions, but am still getting the same error. Still, I appreciate your help and the good few tips you provided. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The obstacles array may have null elements in the middle. What if you add a condition to continue if it's null?

```
function updateOb(e:Event):void {
     // make obstacles move
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
        var ob:Npc = obstacles[i];
        if(!ob) continue;
        move(ob);
        if (player.hitTestObject(ob)) {
        /*if (obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y + 
player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2, player.y - 
player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y + 
player.height/2, true)
        || obstacles[i].hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2, player.y - 
player.height/2, true))*/
            bumpOb(obstacles[i]);
        }
    }
    scoretext.text = String(score);
    if (score == 0) {
        restart();
        gotoAndStop("gameOverLost");
    }
}
```